# Ignore org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptions when transfer xml string to org.w3c.dom.Document?

Tags: java, html, xml, dom, saxparser

I have a lot of html pages (I mean its source codes) represented like java.Util.List of Strings in Java. I need to convert it to Document objects in Java (from the package org.w3c.dom).

I do it this way with DocumentBuilderFactory and Document:

```
public static org.w3c.dom.Document inputStream2Document(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setValidating(false);
    org.w3c.dom.Document parse = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputStream);
    return parse;
}
```

Some of the pages are transformed the right way but there is a problem that there are some other pages with for example wrong written attributes and it is not valid (attributes without ="" ... so it looks like

```
<a href="somepage.html" someattr>
```

for wrong written attribut called "someattr"). And in this cases I get exceptions, for example

```
Nested exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7558; columnNumber: 71; Element type "a" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

or

```
Nested exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 109; columnNumber: 32; The string "--" is not permitted within comments.
```

Is there any way to say to DocumentBuilderFactory that he should ignore this exceptions? I want to convert these pages to Document too and I do not mind that they are not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a href="somepage.html" someattr>` is not XML, so an XML parser will never be able to parse it, but it does look like reasonable *HTML* so you could try an HTML parser such as [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) instead of an XML parser.  There are good examples on NekoHTML's [usage page](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/usage.html) showing how to parse both complete documents and fragments of HTML into DOM nodes.

```
import org.cyberneko.html.parsers.DOMParser;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import java.io.StringReader;

DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
InputSource in = new InputSource(new StringReader(theHtmlString));
parser.parse(in);
Document doc = parser.getDocument();
```

Answer (score 0):

An XML parser can parse only well-formed XML (or, it's the same, XHTML). The pages giving errors are not well-formed, that is they are not XML, so an XML parser is simply not appropriated.

However, if the only problem is the presence of such attributes without a value, you could try to preprocess the input file to remove those attributes using a regular expression.

Comment: And do you know if there is some other way to convert my not well-formed XHTMl pages represented in String to Document object? I write crawling plugin for Apache Nutch so I don't know the structure of this pages in advance... so a regular expression is hard to apply to cover all possibilities.

Comment: A crawler should not try to parse HTML as XML. Are you interested only in the plain text (text visible in the browser) of those pages? In this case you could strip all tags using a regular expression.

Comment: Well, I am interested in all content of those pages... I have NodeWalker and search in elements and attributes. I will try a NekoHTML as it is written below, we will see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I tried NekoHTML and it is working now... jTidy was my second option I wanted to try. Have a nice day!